# SQL Transform of raw data into summary table?

Tags: sql, database

I have a table full of survey data which I need to transform into a nice summary table.   The survey question was (for example) "Rank your restaurant preferences in order".   The raw data looks like:

```
CUST_ID   WENDYS_RANK   MCDONALDS_RANK   BURGERKING_RANK
   1          First          Third           Second
   2          Second         First           Third
   3          None           First           Second
   4          Second         Third           First
(repeat for 100,000+ records)
```

I need to turn this into a nice table that looks like:

```
NAME     NUM_FIRST       NUM_SECOND        NUM_THIRD
Wendys      1              2                  0
McDonalds   2              0                  2
BK          1              2                  1
```

But it's been so darn long since I did a transformation like this I not only forgot how to write the SQL, I forgot what this transformation is called, which makes it hard to google.   Can anyone help me?

Thanks...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I think you need to use PIVOT in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select 'Wendys',
       sum(case when Wendys_Rank = 'First' then 1 else 0 end) as Rank1,
       sum(case when Wendys_Rank = 'Second' then 1 else 0 end) as Rank2,
       sum(case when Wendys_Rank = 'Third' then 1 else 0 end) as Rank3
from surveydata
union all
select 'McDonalds',
       sum(case when McDonalds_Rank = 'First' then 1 else 0 end) as Rank1,
       sum(case when McDonalds_Rank = 'Second' then 1 else 0 end) as Rank2,
       sum(case when McDonalds_Rank = 'Third' then 1 else 0 end) as Rank3
from surveydata
union all
select 'BK',
       sum(case when BK_Rank = 'First' then 1 else 0 end) as Rank1,
       sum(case when BK_Rank = 'Second' then 1 else 0 end) as Rank2,
       sum(case when BK_Rank = 'Third' then 1 else 0 end) as Rank3
from surveydata;
```